# Extending RTF Editor

Tags: experience-manager, gui-extensions, rtf

I have a requirement where client wants to put images in RTF content by just putting the Image URLs(absolute URLs) and not using Tridion DAM items. I thought of using CK Editor's Image plugin to do the same. After reading so many articles, i am not sure of CK Editor will work for me or not. Also, I am not very sure what all configurations and functions to be used in js file to make the editor's client. And on top of it I don't want to open a second Pop up to fill the content. Will it be possible anyhow?

Comment: Next time, please try, share what you've tried and then ask specifically where you got stuck to get the most helpful answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply paste the absolute image URL in your rich text source.  You also have the option to create MM components using an external image URL. I don't believe you will need to do anything custom here.

As far as extending the Tridion GUI  to use CK, you can, but IMHO it's over engineering.

Comment: I can do the same in CMS RTF source but same does not work in Experience Manager and customer is more interested in working with XPM. There I simply cannot put absolute URL's of images. Do I have an option to create Multimedia components using an external image URL, I have not checked it till now. How can I do it , can you brief me about it. Further, whatever I should do , Content author should be able to add new URLs in XPM

Comment: I tried using External image url, but my url is of external media bank url having document id and some other parameters but not having any asset extension as such (.jpeg etc) and hence its not allowing me to save the component

Comment: Strip the extension in the RTF resolver - and if you're extending to resolve on inserting into the RTF you'd need to extend there when making the http request.

Comment: how can I do the same, can you plz elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

If you very specific to CK editor, you can refer GUI extension on [Paste Special Cross Browser Extension](http://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/pastespecial.aspx)

It will help you understand, how to use, CK editor in Tridion.

Comment: Hi raj, i already went thru that. Plz tell me one thing how to create client for my editor?

Answer (score 2):

As Nick suggests, there is out of the box functionality to add images into rich text fields. If you're not seeing the add image icon in the Ribbon Toolbar it's possible it's been excluded by configuration - see the link [here [login required]](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US#docid=task_14_2DDAFF2CF95E4430AA0F27AD7A91B5F8&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=Schema_TextFields_CreatingFormat.xml&resource=&inner_id=&eventType=lcContent.loadDoctask_14_2DDAFF2CF95E4430AA0F27AD7A91B5F8).

If you're seeing the add image icon but are unable to add images through this supported method then please update your question with a use case and ideally any errors/screenshots you can add - remember the more info you give us, the more relevant the help we can offer.

Comment: I can see image icon both in CMS and XPM and can insert images using the icon but the requirement is to use external image urls, we can't keep images in Tridion for now. And I know in CME, I can put the image tag in source of RTF but I need the same to be work out in XPM on the fly.

Comment: "we can't keep images in Tridion for now" - this infers it may change - you can store just the link to the image in a component or use a naming convention and extend the RTF Resolver; [extImg:http://xyz] (in fact you can still use a multimedia component for externally stored content - you'd still get a popup and this is much better for non-technical editors). If you want to resolve the target and render the image it assumes that the machines on which editors are managing content have http access to said target.

Comment: 1)I tried External URL in multimedia, but my url is not an usual image url for example -- url is not like :http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/38/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_010.jpg, instead its something like  www......./download.do?documentId=36233&binaryType=prvw&downloadTypeString=1 so in this case, I am not able to keep the same in multimedia component. 2) Now comes to extend RTF resolver : I want to know the process of doing the same. I am interested in using a CKEditor's image plugin in which there is a feature of providing image url and image gets render. Plz help on this.

Comment: Step 1 is for you to learn how to make GUI Extensions.  This is described in the documentation here: http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/ui.xql?action=html&resource=login.html.  Step 2 is to read the various blogs and look at the Powertools project.  Finally, figure out how to tie in the CK Editor.